# How to create HTTP Web server in C# handling multiple routes?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Listener (that listens multiple routes). But I don't manage to find the right solution.
My problem is : I am running locally Ngrok (on my 8000 port), and an API is sending JSON (with REST request) to my ngrok address. How can I correctly listen the routes called by the API in CSharp ?

Comment: Nope ! Do you have an example ?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment and posted it as an answer. The topic is a bit large to provide an example in a Stackoverflow answer, but if you look at the "getting started" tutorials, you should get the idea pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
My route was : http://localhost:8000/foo/bar
To correct the problem, I have changed the route in : http://+:8000/foo/bar

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? Looks like it's exactly what you need.

Comment: That's too complex for what I want I think. I am searching for something like "http.HandleFunc()" in Go.

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato, too complex for what? Your requirements aren't very clear. What do you want to do with the API requests? Send a response, or just intercept them?

Comment: Yes.. Sorry. I just want to intercept them, read them and send a HTTP 200 as response.

Comment: For example :
The API sends a POST request  at http://8376de2f.ngrok.io/actions/light/start/ (an http tunnel generated by Ngrok) sending a json, and I want to intercept this request.

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato, you can use an [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Comment: I set the prefixes at the wanted values. And I listen with the ''GetContext''method. But nothing is happening after the api sends a request...

Comment: Another detail: in ngrok, I see the correct route called, but I get a 502 Bad gateway.

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato, it looks like the request never reaches your listener. I don't know anything about ngrok, but it's probably a routing issue.

Comment: I will search another solution, thanks for your help !